# How can I describe the sound when an apple hits the floor?

Tags: word-request, onomatopoeia

In my story there is a scene where someone uses magic to drop an apple to the ground. What word can I use to describe that?

Edit: Since some people have asked me to clarify a bit, the scene goes like this.

A non believer sitting under a tree asks a mage to show proof that magic exists. The magician proceeds by dropping several apples from the tree.

Thunk.(the first one falls).

Thunk. Thunk. Thunk. (3 more).

Thunk. (The last one falls on the head of the non believer for good measure).

I think thunk sounds really weird here so I am looking for an alternative.
I'll also clarify that I'm by no means a writer and I'm just writing a story for an assignment. If you have any criticism of the blurb I showed here then I'll be happy to hear it.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! There's a lot of us willing to help people who are learning English, but we like to know what you've already tried, researched or thought of. What are your thoughts, and why aren't you happy with them? There are lists of onomatopoeia online - have you checked any? What makes it hard for you to choose one?

Comment: What sound do *you* think it sounds like—roughly? My impression might be quite different from yours, and giving words that only describe my impression wouldn't be useful to you.

Comment: Ah. We're very much into matters of opinion and writing advice here, rather than really being about learning English, I think. As such, I won't put an answer as an answer, but I'll say this here - *thunk* is a perfectly appropriate word for the sound. *Thud* would also work, and other words might be suitable if the apple is, for example, breaking when it hits the ground. You can use one word repeatedly  for the effect - it can be faintly comical - or use several if you prefer to have variety.

Comment: What sort of surface is it landing on? You say "ground". There's many types of ground, ranging from soft peat where I'm not sure there would even be a sound to hard packed dirt, where your thunk might not be too far off.

Answer (score 1):

*Thunk* is a valid onomatopoeia, although it isn't the first one I would reach for.  Personally, I'd prefer *thud* instead, as *thunk* feels more like a hollow, drumlike sound than the ground typically provides.  Of course, if your ground is raised flooring, *thunk* could very well be appropriate.

Use of onomatopoeia in general can be very comical, so I would be careful of their application.  Strangely, some onomatopoeia are idiomatically more comical than others.  Aside from the sound being slightly different, *thunk* sounds much more amusing than *thud*.  Idiomatically, *thunk* is more frequently used for slapstick, while *thud* is often used for more serious situations.

You might want to consider using both.  At first, *thud* with the apples landing on the soft ground, no drum like echo, and using the word that has a bit more gravitas to showcase the watcher's beliefs being changed.  Finally, *thunk* on the head, suggesting that the asker was less than intelligent (head is hollow -> hollow *thunk* sound), wrapping it up with some comedy.

Comment: I feel like _thunk_ is a good onomatopoeia word, but _thud_ is a good noun or verb. In other words, I’d be more likely to say, “The apples fell with a thud” than to say, “The apples fell. _Thud. Thud. Thud_.” I do like _thunk_ for the sound. (Just one opinion, though, I don’t think there are any fixed rules about this.)

Answer (score -3):

You could say for instance:

> The apple **hit** the ground.
>
> The apple **burst on** the ground.
>
> The apple **bursts on** the ground.
>
> The apple **burst loudly on** the floor.